# Is it possible to translate contents of a block with Drupal 6?

Tags: 6, i18n-l10n

I am working on a project to translate the contents of a block I created. From what I have seen I might have to use hook_menu instead of hook_block. Is this true?

Comment: Still code snippet is missing my friend , having a block of data you would need hook_block , but how you have implemented your hook may lead to no result

Comment: I wrote this one hoping it was a better question than the last one.  But I have just posted code on the first question.